# Normalize different collections with a pre-flatted array a.k.a. joins

Tags: redux, normalizr

All normalizr examples are focused on nested objects they are expecting an API result that looks like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}
```

But I actually found that the following format where you have to do the collections joins yourself is the one I'm dealing with the most, can I use normalizr to handle this case for me?

```
Posts [{ _id: 1, name: 'post text 1', userId: 5, locationId: 8}]

Locations [{ _id: 8, name: 'New York'}]

Users [{ _id: 5, name: 'John Doe', country: 'US'}]
```

expected result:

```
{
  results: [1], // posts ids
  entities: {
    posts: {
      1: { name: 'post text 1', userId: 5, locationId: 8 }
    },
    users: {
      5: { name: 'John Doe', country: 'US' }
    },
    locations: {
      8: { name: 'New York' },
    }
  }
}
```

Docs/github issues nothing mentions it as far as I could find

Comment: Your data already looks normalized. Why are you trying to use something you don't need?

Comment: @PaulArmstrong I want to make it easier to update/delete documents based on the object id, instead of having to loop through the array every time to remove, update. The reducers are getting more verbose and I think it might even give some performance boost, thoughts? Edit: Overall usage of this requires "joins" on the client side when ever I want to display a post it has to do many loops to get the whole post object, otherwise it could be just simple reference. e.g. post.location = location[post.locationId] vs a loop on the locations array to find it.